# Merge or concat two df by index

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have the following issue: I want to concat or merge two dataframes with different length and partly different indexes:

data1:

| index | data1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 |
| 2 | 37 |
| 3 | 18 |
| 7 | 49 |

data2:

| index | data2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 74 |
| 3 | 86 |
| 4 | 12 |
| 6 | 97 |
| 12 | 35 |

They should be merged in the way, that the output looks like:

| index | data1 | data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | NaN |
| 2 | 37 | 74 |
| 3 | 18 | 86 |
| 4 | NaN | 12 |
| 6 | NaN | 97 |
| 7 | 49 | NaN |
| 12 | NaN | 35 |

I hope you can help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
out = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
print(out)

# Output
       data1  data2
index              
1       16.0    NaN
2       37.0   74.0
3       18.0   86.0
4        NaN   12.0
6        NaN   97.0
7       49.0    NaN
12       NaN   35.0
```

Or you can use `merge`:

```
out = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

Or you can use `concat`:

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sort_index()
```